# Legal ways of playing old games that aren't for sale any longer

Tags: backwards-compatibility, legal

There are a few old games that I want to play again (mostly [Earthbound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EarthBound) for the SNES), however I am finding it REALLY hard to get hold of a copy for a good price, as well as the requirement of purchasing a SNES to play it on...

I'd absolutely love to support the game, but the only realistic scenario I can find is having to use an emulator and rom (*illegally*), something I want to avoid.

I understand it will be different depending on the game and platform, I am just curious if there any moral and legal options of playing these little gems again?

Comment: For older PC games some companies are smart enough to re-release them for very low prices (I got the entire Commander Keen pack for $5 on Steam).

Comment: Being a huge Earthbound fan myself, I believe you are sadly out of luck for the game. If you want to play Earthbound legally you will have to buy a copy from ebay, craigslist or some other such site. Starmen.net (a large EB fan site) has been leading petitions & such for awhile to get the game re-released & there has been little to no headway in getting NOA to release it again.

Comment: What about when copyright expires (20 years?) Doesn't downloading the ROM become legal after that?

Comment: Copyright, sadly, takes 70 years for European countries and 95-120 years for the US.

Comment: @XSlicer Non-expired copyright in the US is more accurately "indefinite" so long as Disney continues to lobby for copyright extension every time Mickey Mouse's copyright is almost up. And yes I am serious and yes that is why our copyright lasts so 
long.

Comment: For what it's worth Mother 2 ***was*** re-released for the GBA. If you don't mind playing in a language you can't read, you can certainly play it now. http://www.amazon.com/Game-Boy-Advance-Mother-Selection-Japanese/dp/B000E5EMBO

Comment: Earthbound is now available for Virtual Console on the Wii U, in the Nintendo eShop.

Answer (score 57):

Basically, if it's not on something like [WiiWare](http://www.nintendo.com/games/gameGuide), [Playstation Network](http://us.playstation.com/psn/), or [Good Old Games](http://www.gog.com/), or re-released ala many of the Nintendo era Final Fantasy games, then you're going to have trouble finding copies and the equipment needed to play them.  The fact that certain games are simply nearly impossible to purchase anymore is often the excuse for abandonware or ROM sites.  It is worth pointing out that if you buy a copy on ebay for $100, the company that owns the game won't actually see any of that money.  Whether this goes against your moral compass is up to you.

That said, legally, it'd be against the law if you download a game, even if it's not being sold anywhere.  Fortunately, more companies are joining the bandwagon of releasing older games for new audiences, so it's become easier to find old games for sale legally.

Comment: In addition, some companies released their old games as freeware (without any warranties that they'll work at all, of course). Examples are Arena, Daggerfall, Beneath a Steel Sky, SimCity and several others. As usual, [Wikipedia has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_commercial_video_games_released_as_freeware) ...

Comment: It's not hard to find a SNES or any other old console that was released in the US. Most goodwill's, salvation army stores, etc... have them in bulk. Any flea market has at least 10 vendors w nintendo games and consoles. A very specific game may be harder to get... but the systems are dead easy.

Comment: cinemaware used to provide their old Amiga games for free downloads & use with emulators, but now the site sells remakes of original games on PC...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - About Cinemaware now selling their games. I have a licensed copy of such an anthology from Steam and it's ability to work in GNU\Linux via Wine is a bit sketchy. The free versions would have worked in GNU\Linux UAE just fine. It's not that I don't want to pay for these things, its the fact that these things are hard to get working on modern hardware. Even the A500 Mini requires you to load the games via USB and there is no 3.5 floppy support. That is absurd. I should have never let my Amiga go. She would love me even now that the mother of my children has stopped.

Answer (score 21):

Using ROM images from the net, or even from a copy of a game you own, is illegal.
Period.

[Here is Nintendo's official take on it](http://nintendo.com/corp/legal.jsp#download_rom)

If you want to be legal, you have to buy the original system or a licensed re-issue and the original ROM.

As these games are out of circulation, and as such are practically relics by modern media standards, you've got to choose your battles.

**Finding Them Cheap/Free:**

If you want to be thrifty and save a buck, you're going to have to hunt around and do the leg work. These items can be found at many vintage/thrift/flea market locations... often for 99¢ So you could scour the wastelands and possibly score one. It won't be MIMB... But it'll play your games.

If you REALLY love the game just buy it. No price can be put on love!
Own it and treasure it. Archive it.
Take pictures of it with you on vacation and frame them.

And check Craigslist. People often GIVE AWAY old stuff like this.

You are essentially collecting art and design from the past... just with the added bonus of light, sound and interactivity.  Sometimes really amazing pieces of the historical past of video games fetch VERY high prices. If that is the case, just owning it can be a fight. Be prepared.

**Places to Buy Old Games:**

There are a lot of places that ship and have online inventory or are only a phone call away.

I can personally recommend **[eStarland](http://www.estarland.com/index.asp?page=NintendoSuper)** - They have long been a leader in online retro and import game support.

**[8 bit and up](http://getreadytogame.com)** / 212-674-0201 - Very cool owner, and great shop.

**[Video Games NY](http://videogamesnewyork.com)** / (212) 539-1039 - Has a huge selection

You can also purchase a reissued console that plays both NES and SNES (and Sega's SMS/Genesis - score!) cartridges for about $30

[CNES/SNES/Genesis FC3 Plus Gaming System](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003Y5AHPG)

These systems support the original cartridges. And are also legal.

**tl:dr**

In short, collecting vintage via the internet isn't always cheap.
To save money you're can try questing around the country side of suburbia. MILLIONS of SNES systems are always around. Plus it's always good to get out of the house, off the net and meet your neighbors!

But, unless you own a time machine, be prepared to be the high bidder or forever be incomplete in your collection if you're after a hot or controversial title.

Good luck!

Comment: "Using ROM images from the net, or even from a copy of a game you own, is illegal. Period." Taking offense to this line. There's nothing illegal with using a legitimately-backed up ROM copy, just as there's nothing illegal with burning an extra copy of your music to listen to in your car. Nintendo likes to scare you into thinking it's illegal, however.

Comment: First off, It's absolutely illegal to download it from the net, regardless of whether you own a copy. Full stop, end of discussion. As for making the copy yourself, I'd refer you to the *many* discussions regarding the DMCA and it's anti-circumvention provisions.

Comment: I strictly meant backing up your own copies. As for many old games, there is little to no actual circumvention going on other than plugging it into a device that happens to read the data off the chips.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I suggest you read http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/misinterpreting-copyright.html . It's neither wrong nor strictly illegal, it's merely against the *interpretation* of copyright being pushed by most of these large companies. Unfortunately its been codified by the DMCA, but that doesn't make it worth obeying.

Comment: @Xkeeper I'm personally on the crasic side of the discussion. But, this person is asking about a Nintendo game. And I'm referencing how Nintendo see's it's rights as copyright holders, as he is asking about a Nintendo property. Should theorise find himself in court w Nintendo, that is what he can expect to defend himself against.

Comment: @Crasic: Civil disobedience, and choosing to disobey and unjust law is all well and good, and if you feel the DMCA is unjust, I won't disagree with you. But let's not deny reality and claim that the DMCA isn't law. It is. I never made any statements about right or wrong, I tend not to bring up my own personal views when I get dragged into discussions of IP law here - I'm more concerned with ensuring that whatever discussion does happen does so with correct facts as it's basis.

Comment: @crasic Which is to say: While the GNU's position is admirable, and while strong arguments can be made that copyright law, as it exists now, is restrictive, excessive, not particularly well limited in time, and inconsistent with the constitutional intent of the framers, that does not change what the law is, or the settled interpretation thereof by the courts. The policy here at Gaming.SE is not based on what is *right*, but rather on what is *legal*, for a variety of reasons. If you think the law is unjust, work to change it, don't try to deny the laws existence.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz it depends on the jurisdiction you're in, for example, I can freely download anything in my juristiction. The US copyright law is not valid everywhere in the world.

Comment: @Alexanderpas - first off, you overstate just how broad your rights are in the Netherlands, though certainly, they're broader than here in the US. That said, while there is some jurisdictional variance, the fundamental provisions involved, *including* anti-circumvention measures, hold in nearly all developed countries, thanks to a number of international treaties. Above and beyond that, SOIS Inc. is a US company. When in doubt, obeying US law is a pretty smart default position around here.

Comment: I know this is old, but just a quick reminder that this can change from country to country. Here it is indeed legal to download any software for 48 hours. You can download it and even use it legally if you have the physical copy. If you are coming here, and you are in the airport, and police request to see your notebook, for any reason (yes, the federales can do that), and if you have say, ZNES with an Super Mario ROM, they will request the Phisical cartridge on the spot, otherwise, you will be charged.

Comment: @HugoRocha I can't believe that would actually happen. And this 24/48 hour thing is rubbish, isn't it?

Comment: @Hiccup not in Brazil. It is actually legal. There is even a advise about that on nintendo old brazilian website. The number of the law is 9.610. There is a addendun that states on this time limit.

Comment: @Hiccup also, I saw this question: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/795/what-exactly-does-the-law-state-about-emulation-and-roms Which there a answer that states on the contrary. Every software here you can download for 24 hours, for testing purposes (if indulged, you have tu justify the testing that was done). You can read and research more about the law I posted about.

Comment: @Hiccup also I want to state that I am not a lawyer; Therefore, I'm just commenting on it. Idk if there are exceptions on how does that work. But anyone is free to research on what I posted about.

Answer (score 19):

A lot of the other answers are long-winded and in-depth, so I'll take the short route.

You basically have three options:

1. Buy a copy of the game. Used game store, yard sale, eBay, pick your poison. This only works if the game is still available or still working; some games with battery-powered save-RAM (or worse, battery-powered program-RAM, like some arcade boards) will cease functioning, so this won't be an option. The older the game or the less copies that were made, the more expensive it can be, up to several thousand dollars if you want to "legitimately" play a very rare game. Note that the original vendors get none of the money from this option.
2. Get it off your favorite official download source. Virtual Console, PSN, X-Box Live. This only works if the game has actually been released on the service, which requires that the owning company still exists, still has the proper licenses, and such things. This is why you'll never see Earthbound on there -- lawyers afraid of licensing issues due to the music and references. Note that even if a game does see release, they're usually modified from the originals. Tecmo Bowl, for example, has all of the team names and players removed.
3. There is no three. If you've got to this step and still don't have your game, sorry. There's really nothing more you can do. Your only option is to find a copy of it online, download it, and pledge to support your favorite developers should they ever release the game again, or perhaps purchase related merchandise. Writing a letter to the developers inquiring about a re-release optional, but may make you feel better.

Sorry to disappoint, but in many cases you will end up going to option three.

Comment: Point #3 is factually untrue.  There may not be a _legal_ third option, but that doesn't mean it's accurate or correct to pretend that no third option exists.  You can, as the accepted answer does, point out that the option exists without advocating it or implying that it would be legal.

Comment: @aroth The question *explicitly asked* for *legal* options.

Answer (score 6):

In terms of legality, purchasing the game is the only way to do it. This can either be through tracking down a physical copy of the game or going through one of the licensed distributors of the virtual content. If you want to be "legal" there's no way around those options.

That said, me going to my local used game store and picking up a copy of Chrono Trigger for 100 bucks did nothing for Nintendo or Square. You're getting into the whole issue of reselling used games which the industry is not a fan of anyway.

Neither option supports the developer at this point, but one is definitely legal. You decide what that's worth to you. Personally, if I don't care enough about a game to hunt it down for a ridiculous resale price (damn those nostalgic feelings) I just don't bother unless it gets a virtual release.

Answer (score 4):

A growing number of games are becoming available on console marketplaces such as the Wii Virtual Console and the XBox Live Arcade.  This is a convenient way to play older games through legal channels.

Since you mentioned earthbound by name - it [is available](http://earthbound.nintendo.com/) on the Wii U virtual console.

Comment: Doubtful. http://earthboundcentral.com/2009/02/earthbound-legal-issues/ happily points out a whole host of potential legal issues; silly American stereotypes would hardly be something they would worry about.

Comment: The last part of this answer is now obsolete: Earthbound is [now available for the Wii U](http://earthbound.nintendo.com). Also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EarthBound): *"In 2013, EarthBound was reissued and given a worldwide release for the Wii U Virtual Console following many years of fan lobbying, marking its debut in many territories including Europe."*

Comment: Its also true to say that "A growing number of games are being delisted from console marketplaces XBox Live Arcade." which puts us back to square one. [RIP Scott Pilgrim vs the World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Pilgrim_vs._the_World:_The_Game) :(

Answer (score 4):

Gametap is a fantastic site that is fairly cheap and has legal access to thousands of older games.

Answer (score 4):

Services like [GameTap](http://www.gametap.com) offer games to play (often emulated) legally via licensing from the copyright holders.

Although I believe its mostly arcade games as I couldn't find any Nintendo/Sony/Sega games in their retro section.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst the other answers deal primarily with re-releases or legal sites to play ROMs of games, I thought I'd share an option that has been an excellent addition to my living room: The **[RetroN 5](http://hyperkin.com/Retron5/)!**

[image: Retron 5 Black Console]

The RetroN 5 plays the **original** game cartridges for:

- NES
- Famicom
- SNES
- Super Famicom
- Mega Drive
- Genesis
- Game Boy
- Game Boy Color
- Game Boy Advance
- Master System (via Power Base Converter)

#### How it works

The RetroN dumps the ROM to the console, and plays the game via emulation at 720p. This allows the player to create/load save states, adjust the output resolution and/or filters and scanlines, and modify other options as well.

Note however, that measures have been taken to make sure you cannot just load it up with ROMs from the internet (nor from your personal collection of cartridges): **you still need to have the game inserted to play that game**.

It's one of the greatest (or worst, depending on who you talk to) things about it - you aren't tempted to just load up 200+ ROMs and leave your cartridges in the drawer gathering dust - it forces you to use original cartridges from your physical collection.

#### Upsides

- Outputs over HDMI
- Auto-adjusts for region and screen refresh rate (both of which can also be manually overridden if need be),
- supports original console-controllers
- Save/Load states
- Can back-up and restore game saves to the cartridges themselves. Think your copy of Pokemon Gold/Silver/Crystal's [save-state battery is about to die](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233683/why-does-my-pok%C3%A9mon-gold-cartridge-seem-to-forget-saved-gameplay/233685#233685)? back up the save to the Retron, replace the battery, and reload the save onto the cartridge!

What's more, **any** controller can be used to play **any** game, so if you want to see what it's like playing Sonic with a NES controller, you can.*

<sub>* It's weird for about 5 minutes, then you get used to it :P</sub>

#### Downsides

The only downsides I have for the RetroN are:

- The 'RetronN's default wireless controller suffers from about 4-5ms of input lag, which **doesn't** occur using original controllers (Mega Drive, NES etc).
  It might not sound like much, but it is very noticeable especially on games where timing and frames are everything *cough* Battletoads *cough*

  My suggestion would be to look into getting some OG controllers and relegate the wireless one to games where input lag does not matter too much (Pokemon etc).
- Not something I've come across personally, but apparently not all games are currently supported. Note that some games do show up as 'Unknown Cartridge' - this may just mean that the game is not in their list of games, however it may still work. (although more games are added in each update)
- Speaking of updates, the system has no internet/wireless connection capabilities, and has to be updated via an SD card, which can be a pain if you don't have an SD card reader/writer)

#### Other Options

There are other retro consoles out there, such as [AT Games' Retro Consoles](http://www.atgames.net), but I haven't tested them so I can't speak for their quality. Feel free to suggest them in the comments.

---

<sub>Note: I am not affiliated with Hyperkin or the Retron 5, I just use one and it's pretty great</sub>

Comment: Wasn't part of the OP's problem that he couldn't find a legitimate copy of the game? In my opinion, it's a cakewalk to get the console, but finding a copy of games like Earthbound, Terranigma, Tales of Phantasia, or Illusion of Gaia, for example, are next to impossible or prohibitively expensive. Earthbound is *only* $200 right now on Amazon!

Comment: @nukeforum - sure, but that's been covered pretty succinctly by other answerers :-). The question does ask for legal ways to play old games, hence this answer :-)

Comment: That's fair. I guess I was expecting an all-in-one answer. Still, that's a pretty rockin' device. :)

Comment: I know that system doesn't do Amiga but what about 3.5 inch Amiga floppies and 5.25 inch C64 floppies?  Sadly, the apparently legal A500 Mini doesn't even read 3.5 inch floppies. You have to load the games from USB. Who in the world has un-hacked USB copies of Amiga games unless those games are in the public domain????

Answer (score 3):

Earthbound is now available for Virtual Console on the Wii U and the New 3DS, in the Nintendo eShop. It is also available in Europe, so if you own a Wii U or New 2DS/3DS, purchase it through there.