# What are all the differences between Mother 2 (JP) and EarthBound (US)?

Tags: version-differences, earthbound

From reading [this post](http://earthboundcentral.com/2009/02/earthbound-legal-issues/) I found that what appears to be a significant amount of content was changed when *Mother 2* was localized as *EarthBound* for Western audiences. The article focuses on (possible) copyright-related changes and lists several of them.

Is there a more complete list of changes? Were the changes just due to intellectual property risks or were other changes made beyond translation? I've played the entirety of *EarthBound* but not *Mother 2*, so if there's anything that compares scenes/story elements/whatever that works for me.

Comment: Tried to add an [earthbound] tag but don't have enough rep. Don't know if it's Gaming's policy to tag games rarely brought up anyway (I noticed we only have one other question referencing EB).

Comment: what's the other game? Two questions are enough to keep a tag alive indefinitely.

Comment: @badp [this post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33450/legal-ways-of-playing-old-games-that-arent-for-sale-any-longer) is technically about playing earthbound but was phrased more generally. I might have another question about Mother 3 as well though. Should these be tagged [mother] for the Japanese series or by the specific game? Earthbound is the western name but only 1 out of 3 games is referred to by it.

Comment: eh, that post is not really about the game itself after all. :)

Comment: Given that we have a primarily English language audience here, I think the thing to do is [tag:Mother], [tag:Earthbound] with Mother-2 as a synonym, and [tag:mother-3]. But we can burn that bridge when it shows up tbqh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the very same Tomato (the owner of EarthBound Central and the fan translator of *MOTHER 3* into English) has an extensive comparison site specifically for this question: http://earthboundcentral.com/m2eb/

There's probably more than you ever wanted to know about the differences between these two games. :)

Comment: Epic! Going over it now.