# Why does Pokémon Gold sometimes delete my save data?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I purchased Pokémon Gold, second hand, but it keeps deleting its save data at random intervals. I started playing it the other day, and when I came back a day later, found that the data had been deleted.

[I initially thought this was a similar issue to another question, on here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233683/why-does-my-pok%C3%A9mon-gold-cartridge-seem-to-forget-saved-gameplay), however the user asks concerning their game not being able to save at all. To test, I quickly started a new game, saved, and restarted. The save file was there as it should have been, although when I came back the next day, that new data had also been deleted.

I do not think this could be from a dry battery, either, as if it was, it would not be able to hold a save at all. Why does Pokémon Gold randomly delete my save?

Comment: It could be the battery anyway, maybe it's almost run dry. Try changing it.

Comment: I would, but I don't have one at hand, and I'd rather not buy one if I don't have to.

Comment: you can buy them at Wal-Mart for maybe $4 or $5. they usually have them in the watch section

Comment: TheUnicornMaster Well I'm English so unfortunately that isn't going to work for me.

Comment: @FezodgeIII asda == Walmart and tesco, is French or something (assuming Scotland and England have the same major stores)

Comment: Okay let's not let this turn into a supermarket thread. I can buy them off eBay for a quid, so everybody calm down.

Comment: @FezodgeIII, I interpret this as a similar question to the raised duplicate, but not a duplicate. I have made edits to emphasise the differance, to help counter the VTC snowballing.

Comment: i just used wal-mart as a general store that has everything. but I basically meant you can find them everywhere for a cheap price if you need them